# Can we add filter the req object generated by pinoLogger on express. Like it shows cookie in req object before its logged into the file using ddStream

Tags: node.js, express, pinojs

```
import pinoMulti from 'pino-multi-stream';

const { NODE_ENV, DD_API_KEY, LOGGER_TYPE } = process.env;

const ddStream = {
  stream: ddTransport.createWriteStreamSync({
    //TODO: Investigate better "tags!"
    apiKey: `${DD_API_KEY}`,
    size: 1,
    service: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'dev-aws-auth' : 'dev-local-auth',
    ddsource: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'dev-aws' : 'dev-local',
  }),
};

const prettyStdOut = { stream: pinoMulti.prettyStream({
  colorize: true,
  stream: process.stdout,
})};

export const myLogger =
  LOGGER_TYPE === 'production'
    ? pinoMulti({ streams: [ddStream] })
    : pinoMulti({ streams: [ddStream, prettyStdOut] });
```

Can we add filter the req object generated by pinoLogger on express? Like it shows cookie in req object before its logged into the file using ddStream

**SampleLogs**
Attaching sample logs from the above code. can cookie be filtered out from req object, or before we store the logs in to the file

```
    res: {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": {
        "accept-ranges": "bytes",
        "cache-control": "public, max-age=0",
        "last-modified": "Thu, 24 Sep 2020 21:36:03 GMT",
        "content-type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        "content-length": 28
      }
    }
    responseTime: 15
    logger: "customLog"
    req: {
      "id": 1,
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/",
      "headers": {
        "host": "localhost:8000",
        "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml",
        "**cookie**": "connect.sid=xxxxx.yyyyy",
        "accept-language": "en-us",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "connection": "keep-alive"
      },
      "remoteAddress": "
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hiding header in req and response on express app which was generating secret info in loggers.**
**Add a statement on express app object itself**

```
  const app = express();
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  delete req.headers['cookie']; // should be lowercase
  delete req.headers['set-cookie'];
  next();
});

.use(session({
        secret: 'xxx',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false}))//the session cookie will not be set on the browser unless the session is modified
```